# How to put several Tooltipster tooltips on a picture?

Tags: tooltip, tooltipster

I make tooltips with the JQuery plugin Tooltipster but is confronted with a question. How can I show a tooltip when a user places the cursor at one specific position on a picture, say at the head of a person in a image. The image is in JPG format.

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.Tooltip').tooltipster({
                animation: 'grow',
                delay: 100,
                interactive: true,
                zIndex: 1,
                maxWidth: 300,
                repositionOnScroll: true,
                trigger: 'custom',
                triggerOpen: {
                    mouseenter: true,
                    tap: true
                },
                triggerClose: {
                    mouseleave: true,
                    tap: true
                },
                coord: {
                    left: 100,
                    top: 100
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I try to use the coord but it doesn't work. Did I do something wrong or miss something? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure how the title of your question is related to the question itself. Use area tags to specify a portion of an image and apply the tooltip on it.

Answer (score 1):

> You can achieve this by embedding an `<svg>` element into your html
>   and putting your .jpg inside the `<svg>`. You can then define shapes
>   on top of the image like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/
    <g>
        <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="yourImage.jpg"></image>
        <circle class="Tooltip" cx="263" cy="72" r="4" style="fill: rgb(206, 206, 206);" fill-opacity="0.4">
            <title>Your Tooltip</title>
        </circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Make sure to set the `fill-opacity` to `0` to make the shapes transparent.

**Note:** Tooltipster works well with SVGs, you just need to include a few other scripts to make it work. See [here](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#svg).